# AJAX checkboxes with Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have two rows of check-boxes. When a user clicks on any individual check-box (in a certain row) I want to add a number to my sum in PHP. If he deselects an individual check-box I want to subtract from the total in real time without page refresh. **My question what goes in the data field on my AJAX call?**

***and is this the correct way to do it ?***

### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="standard_form[]" value="A" onclick="processForm()">
<input type="checkbox" name="premium_form[]" value="B" onclick="processForm()">
```

### JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function processForm() { 
        $.ajax( {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'submit_form.php',
            data: '',

            success: function(data) {
                $('#message').html(data);
            }
        } );
}
</script>
```

### PHP

```
    if(IsChecked('standard_form','A'))
    {
      $price += IsChecked('standard_form','A') ? 10 : 0;
    }
   return $price ;
```

---

Comment: value goes in the data field

Comment: Is there a reason the calculation is done through  an AJAX call to PHP and not in the Javascript?

Comment: @theZ because I don't want the calculation to be done on client-side, in-case the users can modify the "value"

Comment: @Edward Well, they can still change the values if they are coming back and being inserted into the DOM. You aren't saving the calculation serverside nor is it tied to a user so it is being lost anyways. A client could even override processForm if they wanted. Client side stuff will always be malleable for a client. Going through a server for stability is pointless if you then return to the client.

Comment: @theZ if that's the case I will keep the calculation server-side. can I do this calculation in PHP asynchronously or do I still need to use Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function processForm() { 
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'submit_form.php',
        data: { checked_box : $('input:checkbox:checked').val()},

        success: function(data) {
            $('#message').html(data);
        }
    } );
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to serialize the form into a JS object, that's what goes into the data field. Here's a simple serialize function, that could be improved, but will give you an idea

```
function serializeForm(form) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
        var el = form.elements[i];
        if (el.name) {
            if (obj[el.name] && obj[el.name].constructor == Array ) {
               obj[el.name].push(el.value);              
            } else if (obj[el.name]) {
               obj[el.name] = [obj[el.name], el.value];
            } else {
               obj[el.name] = el.value;
            }
        }
    }
    return obj; 
}
```

There is a plugin that lets you submit forms with AJAX easily http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ See [jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

Assuming the following HTML

```
<form id="myForm" action="submit_form.php" method="post"> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="standard_form[]" value="A" onclick="processForm()">
  <input type="checkbox" name="premium_form[]" value="B" onclick="processForm()">
</form>
```

You can just do the following to have the form posted with AJAX

```
// attach handler to form's submit event 
$('#myForm').submit(function() { 
    // submit the form 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(); 
    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In checkboxes try `onclick="processForm(this)"`, then, in JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function processForm(elm) { 
        $.ajax( {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'submit_form.php',
            data: elm.name+'='+elm.value,

            success: function(data) {
                $('#message').html(data);
            }
        } );
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to give the data a name, so that it will be accessible using `$_POST['name']` in PHP.